# Python 3: Automating `source env/bin/activate` upon cd-ing to a directory

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Previously I was at

```
> port select --list python
..
python27 (active)
..
```

Now, even after

```
> sudo port select --set python python36
```

and

```
> pip install autoenv==1.0.0
```

I still find that `activate.sh`

```
> which activate.sh
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/activate.sh
```

points to 2.7.

Now I'd like to replace the previous call

```
> echo "source `which activate.sh`" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

with a fresh one for Python 3(.6).

How do I properly engage `autoenv` and `activate.sh` for Python 3.6? I am guessing that the existence of `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`activate.sh` from `autoenv` is written in shell and doesn't mention Python in any way. It should work with any directory that has `.env`. So you actually don't need to reinstall it. But if you still want — `pip install` usually installs for Python 2. Use

```
pip uninstall autoenv
pip3 install autoenv
```

to uninstall `autoenv` for Python 2 and install it for Python 3.

Comment: Looking forward at the stability of the system, when Python 2.x will never even be installed: After running `sudo port select --set pip pip36` (now pip is a symlink to pip36) and `sudo pip install autoenv`, there is no `activate.sh` in my path. I appreciate that `activate.sh` is just a bash file, but it should still appear somehow for a purely 3.x Python installation, no?

Comment: It must appear, bu not neccessary in your path. It could be in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: Ah.. yes.. it did indeed appear (in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin). I can also confirm that it's identical (in timestamp too) to the one installed under 2.7.