# Stability of .emacs under flycheck

Tags: python, emacs, flycheck

To get flycheck working for Python, I had reached a satisfactory `.emacs`, which turned out to require no more than:

```
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

Now after a bit of looking [forward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46079912/704972) at what Python 3.6 will be like, even a two-liner

```
class Foo():
    pass
```

gets a whole slew of warnings:

```
Too few public methods (0/2) [too-few-public-methods]
Class has no __init__ method [no-init]
Old-style class defined. [old-style-class]
Missing class docstring [missing-docstring]
Missing module docstring [missing-docstring]
```

despite that I'm now firmly back in 2.7 (`sudo port select --set python python27`).

Emacs gets us used to being context-agnostic. It usually doesn't matter what is on the system; one gets the same behavior if one starts from an unchanged `.emacs`. What else might have changed in my system to trigger a sudden increase in flycheck warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer.

flycheck [chooses](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/languages.html#python) (silently?) flake8, and if that is not found, it falls back on pylint (and subsequently on pycompile).

The problem was that the symlink `flake8` had vanished. Here is why/how.

After selecting python36 and back

```
~/ > sudo port select --set python python36
~/ > sudo port select --set python python27
```

and after selecting pip36 and back

```
~/ > sudo port select --set pip pip36
~/ > sudo port select --set pip pip27
```

the symlink `/opt/local/bin/flake8` disappears. Only flake8-2.7 is left.

```
> ls -l /opt/local/bin/flake8*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  70 20 Mar 16:35 /opt/local/bin/flake8-2.7 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/flake8
```

What happens, presumably, is that `flake8` points to nothing (`port select` is updated, and the symlink is removed) when you update to Python 3.6 but do not have flake8-36. The symlink cannot be reinstated when you downgrade to Python 2.7 (one of these, perhaps the former, merits a warning—maybe as a minor bug in MacPorts).

```
~/ > sudo port select --list flake8
Available versions for flake8:
    flake8-27
    none (active)
```

The solution is to explicitly point `flake8` to `flake8-27` when you downgrade.

```
~/ > sudo port select --set flake8 flake8-27
Selecting 'flake8-27' for 'flake8' succeeded. 'flake8-27' is now active.
```

And the link comes back and flycheck chooses `flake8` over `pylint`.

```
> ls -l /opt/local/bin/flake8*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  25  7 Sep 09:01 /opt/local/bin/flake8 -> /opt/local/bin/flake8-2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  70 20 Mar 16:35 /opt/local/bin/flake8-2.7 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/flake8
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to setup minor mode hook or only add to programming mode

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)

By setting it to `global` will enable it in every buffer even in text mode like org mode which is not needed. Also might slow things down. :)

Comment: Activating flycheck selectively may indeed be good advice, but it's also a separate issue. Even if flycheck is activated for Python alone, the issue described in this question will arise.